# Rolling 3 years sum grouped by other columns in R

Tags: r

My data frame has only annual data, I want to create a sum of a 3 years period grouped by column name NOC, NAICS, Region.

| NOC | Region | NAICS | Date | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | East | AA | 2010 | 12/31/2010 | 3 |
| 0000 | East | AA | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 4 |
| 0000 | East | AA | 2012 | 12/31/2012 | 0 |
| 0000 | West | BB | 2010 | 12/31/2010 | 100 |
| 0000 | West | BB | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 200 |
| 0000 | West | BB | 2012 | 12/31/2012 | 200 |
| 0000 | North | CC | 2010 | 12/31/2010 | -23 |
| 0000 | North | CC | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 3 |
| 0000 | North | CC | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 20 |

NEW df should look like

| NOC | Region | NAICS | Date | Year | Value | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | East | AA | 2010 | 12/31/2010 | 3 | 7 |
| 0000 | East | AA | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 4 | NA |
| 0000 | East | AA | 2012 | 12/31/2012 | 0 | NA |
| 0000 | West | BB | 2010 | 12/31/2010 | 100 | 500 |
| 0000 | West | BB | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 200 | NA |
| 0000 | West | BB | 2012 | 12/31/2012 | 200 | NA |
| 0000 | North | CC | 2011 | 12/31/2010 | -23 | 0 |
| 0000 | North | CC | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 3 | NA |
| 0000 | North | CC | 2011 | 12/31/2011 | 20 | NA |

I tried this but can't get it to work.

```
df %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region,  NAICS, Date) %>%
  mutate(max = rollapplyr(Value, 1:n() - findInterval(date - 5, Date), sum)) %>%
  slice_max(max) %>%
  ungroup %>%
```

Comment: Please use ```dput()``` to share your data.

Comment: I would be interested to know the reason for having the sum at the first record of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS) %>%
  mutate(Sum = rollsum(Value, 3, fill = NA, align = "left"))
```

Or

```
df %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS) %>%
  mutate(Sum = Value + lead(Value) + lead(lead(Value)))
```

Or using `rollapply`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS) %>%
  mutate(Sum = rollapply(Value, 3, sum, fill = NA, align = "left"))
```

These are all assuming you have complete data (ie, there are no gaps in the data, and it's all evenly spaced (i.e. it doesn't go 2011, 2012, 2014, 2014), which it looks like your data doesn't do. In that case, something like this would be more appropriate:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Year),
        Year = year(Date)) %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS) %>%
  mutate(
        Sum = map_dbl(Date, ~sum(Value[between(Date, .x, .x + years(3))])))
```

However this takes the sum of the next three years of values, which doesn't create a bunch of NAs as in your example, because it just looks for the ones it can find (you can see this as a positive or a negative, depending on your perspective).

OR, if you want to split the data into discrete 3 year groups:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Year),
        Year = year(Date)) %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS) %>%
  # round to the yearest three year chunk
  mutate(Group = round(as.numeric(Date - min(Date))/1462)+1) %>%
  group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS, Group) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Year == first(Year), sum(Value), NA))
```

Comment: The data shows that behaviours such as yours are excluded. The north group has two positions within the year 2011

Comment: @thomas that is true, however it's unclear to me what precisely OP wants, so I just threw a bunch of things out there. There's many ways of creating the desired output with different rules

Comment: Like your answer, I covered both

Answer (score 1):

The `rollapply` function can be used with a fixed window size, when you are sure that the timestamps are equally distributed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df |>
    group_by(NOC, Region, NAICS) |>
    mutate(Sum = rollapply(Value, 3, sum, fill = NA, align = "left"))
```

If the distance between the timestamps is not equal, you will need to use the `rollapply` with a vector of width. This vector can be calculated as described in the following code snippet, where `findIntervall` looks for the boundaries of the intervals.

```
gf <- df |> 
          group_by(Region)|>
          mutate(width = findInterval(Date + 3 , Date) - seq_along(Date) + 1,
          results = rollapply(Value, width, sum, fill=NA, align="left"))
```

However, you do not get the `NA` values. To get that, you would have to come up with some rules for identifying the beginning of a three-year cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
df %>% mutate(rle=row_number(),
             sum=ifelse(rle==1,sum(Value),NA), .by=c(NOC,Region,NAICS)) %>% select(-rle)
```

```r
# A tibble: 9 × 7
    NOC Region NAICS  Date Year       Value   sum
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
1     0 East   AA     2010 12/31/2010     3     7
2     0 East   AA     2011 12/31/2011     4    NA
3     0 East   AA     2012 12/31/2012     0    NA
4     0 West   BB     2010 12/31/2010   100   500
5     0 West   BB     2011 12/31/2011   200    NA
6     0 West   BB     2012 12/31/2012   200    NA
7     0 North  CC     2010 12/31/2010   -23     0
8     0 North  CC     2011 12/31/2011     3    NA
9     0 North  CC     2011 12/31/2011    20    NA
```